# Trouble looping through an array created from a foursquare JSON feed

Tags: php, json, loops, foreach, foursquare

I'm working on a side project and at its core, I need to get a foursquare json feed into an array that i can loop through. My code is below and results in the following error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /homepages/7/d346835943/htdocs/dealrub/results.php on line 56
```

Here is an example of the json feed that i am correctly acquiring:

```
$jsonurl = "http://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=".$lat.",".$lon."&limit=100";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_encode($json, true);

foreach ( $json_output->response->groups[0]->items as $items )
{
     echo "{$items->name}\n";
}
```

Any help as to what i'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. I left the jsonurl without my api key, but it is successfully returning the json results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).
2. Check whether `$json_ouput` is not empty.
3. You are passing `true` as second argument to `json_decode` (assuming you have it right) which means that it returns an associative array.

   Either omit that:

   ```
   $json_output = json_decode($json);
   ```

   or access `items` as array:

   ```
   foreach ( $json_output['response']['groups'][0]['items'] as $items )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You're using json_encode on a string that is already in json. Try json_decode instead ;)