# Foursquare Venues: API & json_decode Issue

Tags: json, api, foursquare

(I've consulted [Trouble looping through an array created from a foursquare JSON feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676546/trouble-looping-through-an-array-created-from-a-foursquare-json-feed), but the code listed there hasn't been working for me)

I operate Foursquare for a business with multiple venues. We want to pull some stats for each venue (e.g. checkin totals, etc.) into various pages on our website. So I signed up for Foursquare's API and created an app in my Foursquare account.

My PHP code on our site is successfully connecting and pulling down venue information from Foursquare--my problem is that I've so far been unable to output the contents of the decoded JSON. I've tried both the associative array approach (json_decode($response, true)) and the non-array approach (json_decode($response)) to no avail.

That said, my goal is to echo specifically some of the stats fields like checkinsCount. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with the for loop below as well as how to reference specific fields within the output, like checkinsCount?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
$curlhandle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUEID?               client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=CLIENTSECREAT");
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($curlhandle);
//echo $response;
// THE ABOVE WORKS -- I'M ABLE TO GET A RESPONSE

curl_close($curlhandle);

$json = json_decode($response, true);
//var_dump($json);
// THE ABOVE WORKS -- I'M ABLE TO SUCCESSFULLY LIST THE VARIABLES AND VALUES

foreach ( $json['response']['groups'][0]['items'] as $items )
// THIS IS NOT WORKING -- I GET BLANK OUTPUT

//THESE ARE THE FIELDS I WANT TO ECHO
mayor
stats->checkinsCount
stats->usersCount
```

Here is a snippet of what shows up in my var_dump:

`["categories"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(24) "4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735" ["name"]=> string(11) "Coffee Shop" ["pluralName"]=> string(12) "Coffee Shops" ["shortName"]=> string(11) "Coffee Shop" ["icon"]=> string(57) "REMOVEDURLPREFIX/img/categories/food/coffeeshop.png" ["parents"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "Food" } ["primary"]=> bool(true) } [1]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(24) "4bf58dd8d48988d16d941735" ["name"]=> string(5) "Café" ["pluralName"]=> string(6) "Cafés" ["shortName"]=> string(5) "Café" ["icon"]=> string(51) "REMOVEDURLPREFIX/img/categories/food/cafe.png" ["parents"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "Food" } } } ["verified"]=> bool(true) ["restricted"]=> bool(true) ["stats"]=> array(3) { ["checkinsCount"]=> int(142) ["usersCount"]=> int(35) ["tipCount"]=> int(4) } ["url"]=> string(18) "http://denison.edu" ["likes"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(0) ["groups"]=> array(0) { } } ["specials"]=> array(0) { } ["photos"]=> array(3) { ["count"]=> int(1) ["groups"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { ["type"]=> string(7) "checkin" ["name"]=> string(24) "Friends' check-in photos" ["count"]=> int(0) ["items"]=> array(0) { } } [1]=> array(4) { ["type"]=> string(5) "venue" ["name"]=> string(12) "Venue photos" ["count"]=> int(1) ["items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(24) "5122de9ce4b0a8206c1158e5"`

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the format of the response from Foursquare. For instance, examine https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3—note how there is no "groups" object returned.

You probably want to use `$json['response']['venue']['mayor']` and `$json['response']['venue']['stats']` to start.